# Material UI: How to align different form elements including pickers in a row?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm very new to material ui so apologies if this has been covered. I have found some similar questions but none demonstrating a solution with multiple form field types.

I have found that material ui date picker does not align correctly with text fields

Code:

```
  <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
    <Grid container direction={'row'} alignItems={'center'}>
      <Grid item>
        <KeyboardDatePicker
          disableToolbar
          variant="inline"
          inputVariant="outlined"
          format="dd-MM-yyyy"
          margin="normal"
          id="date1"
          value={'12-09-2021'}
          KeyboardButtonProps={{
            'aria-label': 'change date',
          }}
          size="small"
          required
        />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
        <TextField id="text1" size="small" variant="outlined" required />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
        <TextField id="text2" size="small" variant="outlined" required />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

This is what it looks like:

[image: Janky alignment]

Adding form labels and helper texts just exacerbates the problem.

Is there any way to get these form fields playing nicely side-by-side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added the `margin="normal"` to `KeyboardDatePicker`. You need to add the same margin for other elements as well. I have also added [`justify: {'space-evenly'}`](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/#interactive) for the Grid container.

```
<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
    <Grid container direction={'row'} alignItems={'center'} justify={'space-evenly'}>
      <Grid item>
        <KeyboardDatePicker
          disableToolbar
          variant="inline"
          inputVariant="outlined"
          format="dd-MM-yyyy"
          margin="normal"
          id="date1"
          value={'12-09-2021'}
          KeyboardButtonProps={{
            'aria-label': 'change date',
          }}
          size="small"
          required
        />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
        <TextField id="text1" size="small" variant="outlined" margin="normal" required />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
        <TextField id="text2" size="small" variant="outlined" margin="normal" required />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
</MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

[Codesandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-mrcpk)